# Empty runtime config for firebase functions when running locally

Tags: node.js, firebase, webpack, google-cloud-functions

So i'm getting the infamous empty functions `config()`  when running functions locally

Error I'm getting:

`It looks like you're trying to access functions.config().stripe but there is no value there. You can learn more about setting up config here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator TypeError: Cannot read property 'test_token' of undefined`

Calling the following from the `functions` folder:

`firebase emulators:start --only functions`

Important info:

- I definitely am running the emulator/serve from the functions
- I did the firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json and
  verified there are indeed values inside the file
- I verified i am using the correct firebase project through the CLI
  and also by caling the functions:config:get through terminal.
- I still get an empty config file when i attempt to run locally which
  makes it so i effectively can not run my functions at all (since they
  rely on these values)
- The values are definitely set on the actual cloud config (this is not a new project or anything)

firebase emulators:start --only functions

I'm using firebase functions version: `3.15.4`

I'm accessing config this way btw:

```
import { config, config as firebaseConfig } from 'firebase-functions';
...
const runtimeConfig = config() as CloudRuntimeConfig;
```

Additional thoughts:

This project has some webpack integrated into it - I'm not sure if its related or not, but just adding it out there as it might be related.

Please! Any help would be greatly appreciated - i'm about to lose it

Answer (score 0):

the issue was that my package.json was pointing me to the `dist/` folder:

`"main": "dist/index.js",`

Therefore, it was looking for the `runtimeconfig.json` file in there (inside `/dist`).

Solution was copying the file/making a new one inside `dist` and then that fixed it!!

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation ([here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#run_the_emulator_suite)). You need to run

> firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json

in your **functions directory**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).